# Reboot loop on trying to load kernel

Tags: assembly, x86, osdev

When I try to boot on qemu I get an endless reboot loop, I was able to narrow it down the line

```
call 0x1000
```

This is my first time delving into osdev and if there are any other things i'm doing wrong please inform me:) thanks in advance!!

```
[org 0x7c00]
[bits 16]
bootdrive db 0x00
xor ax,ax
mov ds, ax
mov ss, ax
mov sp, 0x9c00
mov bp, sp
mov [bootdrive], dl
mov bx, 0x1000
mov dh, 0x01
mov dl, bootdrive

loadkernel:
pusha

push dx

mov ah, 0x02
mov al, dh
mov ch, 0x00
mov dh, 0x00
mov cl, 0x02

int 0x13

pop dx

popa

setgdt:
cli
lgdt[gdtr]

call openA20

call EnablePmode

openA20:

push ax
mov ax, 0x2401
int 0x15
pop ax

ret

EnablePmode:
    mov eax, cr0
    or al, 1
    mov cr0, eax

    jmp (CODE_DESC - NULL_DESC) : Pmode
NULL_DESC:
    dd 0
    dd 0
CODE_DESC:
    dw 0xffff
    dw 0
    db 0
    db 10011010b
    db 11001111b
    db 0
DATA_DESC:
    dw 0xffff
    dw 0
    db 0
    db 10010010b
    db 11001111b
    db 0
gdtr:
    Limit dw gdtr - NULL_DESC - 1
    Base dd NULL_DESC
[bits 32]
    Pmode:
    mov ax, DATA_DESC - NULL_DESC
    mov ds, ax
    mov ss, ax
    mov es, ax
    mov fs, ax
    mov gs, ax


mov ebp, 0x90000
    mov esp, ebp

    call 0x1000

    jmp $

times 510-($-$$) db 0

dw 0xaa55
```

Comment: First off put your data after your code and before the boot signature or the data will be executed as a code.

Comment: Int 13h/ah=2 needs the ES segment register set to the segment you intend to read the sector(s) at in memory. ES:BX point to the buffer.

Comment: `bootdrive db 0x00` is the first instruction to be executed...

Comment: `mov dl, bootdrive` looks wrong. You may heave meant `mov dl, [bootdrive]`

Answer (score 2):

This code has many problems.

First of all,make sure CPU does not execute 0x00.

In line 3,you have `bootdrive db 0`.
It should look like this:

```
[BITS 16]
[ORG 0x7C00]
jmp main
bootdev db 0
main:
```

Second one is you are trying to assign a word(pointer of bootdev) to DL.Which is not correct.it should look like this:

```
mov dl,[bootdev]
```

And you are trying to read Head:0 Cylinder/Track:0 and Sector 2.You think it will load to BX address which is 0x1000. but it will load at [ES:BX].if you want to jump 0x1000,
then make sure ES is 0.

```
xor ax,ax ;AX is 0 now.
mov es,ax ;Thats how you reset ES.
```

You should enable A20 before loading GDT.

Your new code should look like this:

```
[org 0x7c00]
[bits 16]
jmp main
bootdrive db 0x00
main:
xor ax,ax
mov ds, ax
mov ss, ax
mov sp, 0x9c00
mov bp, sp
mov [bootdrive], dl
mov bx, 0x1000
mov dh, 0x01
mov dl, [bootdrive]

loadkernel:
pusha

push dx
xor ax,ax
mov es,ax
mov ah, 0x02
mov al, dh
mov ch, 0x00
mov dh, 0x00
mov cl, 0x02

int 0x13

pop dx

popa

setgdt:
cli
call openA20
lgdt[gdtr]
call EnablePmode
openA20:

push ax
mov ax, 0x2401
int 0x15
pop ax

ret

EnablePmode:
    mov eax, cr0
    or al, 1
    mov cr0, eax

    jmp (CODE_DESC - NULL_DESC) : Pmode
NULL_DESC:
    dd 0
    dd 0
CODE_DESC:
    dw 0xffff
    dw 0
    db 0
    db 10011010b
    db 11001111b
    db 0
DATA_DESC:
    dw 0xffff
    dw 0
    db 0
    db 10010010b
    db 11001111b
    db 0
gdtr:
    Limit dw gdtr - NULL_DESC - 1
    Base dd NULL_DESC
[bits 32]
    Pmode:
    mov ax, DATA_DESC - NULL_DESC
    mov ds, ax
    mov ss, ax
    mov es, ax
    mov fs, ax
    mov gs, ax


mov ebp, 0x90000
    mov esp, ebp


    call 0x1000

    jmp $

times 510-($-$$) db 0

dw 0xaa55
```

And The Kernel:

```
BITS 32
org 0x1000
Start:
mov eax,0xB8000
mov byte [eax],78
mov byte [eax+1],71
jmp $
```

It will print red backgrounded grey "N" to top left.

Happy Coding!